# AngularJS: directive timing issue when using Angular routing

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-routing

My application uses two AngularJS directives: a parent directive that contains multiple instances of a child directive. The rendering of HTML by the child directives is dependent on the width of the containing element associated with the parent directive, so the child directive must query the parent (by calling a method on its controller) to discover this width.

This implementation works fine when used in a static page, but it breaks when used as part of a single-page application that employs Angular's routing mechanism.

Specifically, with routing active, the first time the page is loaded, the HTML renders correctly, but when the page content is updated to reflect different model data, the rendering breaks. This only occurs when the width of the containing element is 100%. If it is set to a fixed width, everything works as expected.

Debugging the issue has shown me that the width of the containing parent element is not valid at the time that the child directives are rendered, so I assume I am doing things in the wrong sequence or failing to follow some aspect of Angular best practice that deals with this kind of timing gotcha.

Is there an event that my directives need to wait for before rendering?

Thanks, in advance.
Tim

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding correctly you are have few child directives that has a width dependency on the parent directive. There are events that you can try on such as $broadcast where the parent directive sends a notification to its children.Once you receive that then you can use $on event and can  your child directives.
I know i am not much constructive in my answer but yes if you have built such a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I am familiar with $broadcast and $on but I am not sure what I should use as a trigger for the broadcast. The fact that my code works fine in a static page but not with routing makes me think there must be some timing event exposed by the routing mechanism that I need to tie into.